# QT Creator forget git username

Tags: git, github, qt-creator

I'm trying to push my project to Github in QT Creator on Linux, I accidently entered my password in the Username dialog and checked remember. Now it keeps asking me for my password at "(password)@github.com"

I can't find anywhere to reset the username in QT Creator. I've checked the git config in both the project and home directory I've grepped for my password through all of the .config directory.

I can push using the command line, it asks for both my username and password, but I just can't do it in QT Creator.

Comment: Can you delete your .git file and start it again? Its a hidden folder at the root of your project. If you do this you will just have to start from git init etc. Again

Comment: maybe. I got around it in the end by changing the remote repository to username@github.com instead of just github, so it's working now, but I can't help but think somewhere in QT creator is my github password in a username field.

Comment: Hello, late anwser. I just did the exact same thing. I did find the password to remove in my KDE wallet. I had to open `kwalletmanager5` (depending on your distro), search for `github.com` and I could remove the entry. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

As a user commented (I am just restating it as an answer) the username and password are stored in KDE Wallet. Just open kwalletmanager5 from a terminal or search KDE Wallet in the applications menu and from there look for something that starts with "kssh" and it should contain your password. Just right click and delete this entry and it should reset.